# Javascript, get the name of a bound function

Tags: javascript

I've created a function and bound the arguments as below.

```
function myFunc(){}

let boundFunc = myFunc.bind(argument);
```

But then I pass this bound function as an argument to another function, where I need to get the name. The following:

```
function doTheThing(callable){
    console.log(callable.name + " did the thing");
}

doTheThing(boundFunc);
```

Prints out `bound did the thing` rather than `myFunc did the thing`. Is there any way to get the name of the bound function?

---

`callable.caller` results in `Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.` and is not browser standard.

Comment: As far as I know, No. `.bind()` returns an entirely new function. So unless you hold an instance of the old function somewhere, you can't determine its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short `callable.name` does work, and produces `bound myFunc`.

---

My version wasn't working because I was using transpiled typescript. This snippet:

```
class MyClass{
  static doTheThing(callable) {}
}

let myFunc = MyClass.doTheThing.bind(null);

function handleCall(callable){
  console.log(callable.name)
}

handleCall(myFunc);
```

produces:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.doTheThing = function (callable) {};
    return MyClass;
}());
var myFunc = MyClass.doTheThing.bind(null);
function handleCall(callable) {
    console.log(callable.name);
}
handleCall(myFunc);
```

The key is the line `MyClass.doTheThing = function (callable) {};` This makes `MyClass.doTheThing` an anonymous function therefore returning undefined for it's name. This results in callable.name returning `"bound " + undefined` or `"bound "`.

So in short, you can get the name of a bound function, but a <s>girl</s> function does not have a name.

Answer (score 4):

Google Chrome v 51.0.2704.103 gives a different result:

```js
function myFunc(){}

let boundFunc = myFunc.bind(null);

function doTheThing(callable){
  console.log(callable.name + " did the thing");
}

doTheThing(boundFunc);
```

It prints `bound myFunc did the thing`, so you could get the original name with `callable.name.substring(6)`

Comment: Also works in FF 49.0a2. Might I suggest `/^bound (.*)$/.exec(callable.name)[1]` for the original name though, as that would not fail silently if the name for some reason did not match the pattern "bound ..."?

Comment: I'm finding that snippet is working for me as well, but the original code doing the same thing isn't.

Comment: @timlyo Could you post your actual code? The one you have in your question can't work, as you're checking if `callable()` returns a truthful value, which it never does. Also check what you're binding to it. The first argument of `bind` is the context, aka whatever you want `this` to refer to.

Comment: The logic in the question isn't important, not really sure why I added it. I've worked out my problem, and am just writing up and answer as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using node (tested now on v9.2.0), try

```
import util from 'util'

function myFunc(){}
let boundFunc = myFunc.bind(null)
let functionInfo = util.format(boundFunc)

console.log(functionInfo) // [Function: bound myFunc]
```

.. and extract it from there